# unable to install mongodb for php 7 on windows 10 64 bit OS?

Tags: php, mongodb

I am a newbie to mongodb, I am trying to install mongodb on my localhost machine which runs on windows 10 with PHP Version 7.1.1, I followed below steps:

```
Step 1: have copied mongodb .dll file from [Link][1] into "C:\xampp\php\ext" folder
Step 2: added "extension=php_mongo.dll" line to php.ini file
Step 3: Modified the PATH Variable to "C:\XAMPP\PHP" in  environment variables
Step 4: restarted the XAMPP server.
```

phpinfo is :

[image: Screenshot]

I have created one test file to check if it has installed successfully or not by adding code "echo phpinfo();" it was showing all the list but except mongodb. Can any one please explain me What's wrong and how to do it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you modifying the correct php.ini file? Check "Loaded Configuration File" attribute in your phpinfo for the correct path.

Comment: I have added a screenshot with highlighting the "Loaded Configuration File" please check it once.